# Why is the compiler dedicating a memory location for storing a redundant variable in this case?

Tags: c++, assembly, gcc, x86-64, atomic

I [wrote this](https://godbolt.org/z/hhsvd9WTv) simple C++ code, to see how atomic variables are implemented.

```
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

atomic<float> f(0);

int main() {
    f += 1.0;
}
```

It is generating this assembly for main in -O3:

```
main:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR f[rip]
        movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR .LC1[rip]
        movd    xmm0, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], eax  ; this line is redundant
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
.L2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]  ; this line is redundant
        movd    edx, xmm0
        lock cmpxchg    DWORD PTR f[rip], edx
        je      .L5
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], eax  ; this line is redundant
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]  ; this line can become  movd    xmm0, eax
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        jmp     .L2
.L5:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
f:
        .zero   4
.LC1:
        .long   1065353216
```

It is using the atomic compare and exchange technique to achieve atomicity. But there, the old value is being stored in the stack at [rsp-4]. But in the above code, eax is invariant. So the old value is preserved in eax itself. Why is the compiler allocating additional space for the old value? Even in -O3!! Is there any specific reason to store that variable in the stack rather than in registers?

**EDIT:** Logical deduction -

There are 4 lines that use `rsp-4` -

```
mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], eax    --- 1
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]    --- 2  <--.
mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], eax    --- 3     | loop
movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]   --- 4  ---'
```

Lines 3 and 4 have absolutely nothing else in-between, and hence 4 can be re written using 3 as
`movd    xmm0, eax`.

Now, when going from line 3 to 2 in the loop, there is no modification to `rsp-4`(nor `eax`). So it implies that lines 3 and 2 in sequence together collapse to
`mov    eax, eax`
which is redundant by nature.

Finally, only line 1 remains, whose destination is never used again. So it is also redundant.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen yep, it is pretty straightforward. After seeing that, I moved onto floats ;)

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB They were responding to a slightly misleading comment of mine wondering if this was related to float not having an atomic addition.

Comment: clang's code is more sensible: https://godbolt.org/z/qeGK8KzW4.  This looks like a simple missed optimization bug, you could report it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any specific reason to store that variable in stack rather than in registers?

At the end of the day, atomics exist for inter-thread communication, and you can't share a register across threads.

You might think that gcc *could* detect local variable atomics that are never shared with anything else and demote them to a regular variable. However:

1. I personally don't see what this brings to the table since you shouldn't be using atomics in these cases.
2. The standard appears to prohibit such an optimization anyways:

**[intro.races-14](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-14)**

> The value of an atomic object M, as determined by evaluation B, shall be the value stored by some side effect A that modifies M, where B does not happen before A.

The key word here is **side effect**, which means that the modification of the actual memory storage is not up for debate. It HAS to happen.

As far as the revised question goes:

> But in the above code, eax is invariant

It's unfortunately not. `cmpxchg` both reads and writes to `eax`, so it needs to be reassigned at each iteration of the loop.

The loop is needed because in order to perform a `+= 1` on an atomic float. The compiler has to keep trying until it manages to do the read-increment-write sequence fast enough that the atomic doesn't change in the meantime.

Comment: `you can't share a register across threads` Intermediate results need not be shared to other threads. Anyways stack is not shared with other threads.. (I have edited my question to mark exactly the lines which I am seeing redundant. Please check it.)

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB sharing a pointer to a stack allocated object to some other thread is perfectly feasible. As far as intermediate results go, I'll see if I can update the answer to reflect the revised question.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I have revised the answer

Comment: Still `[rsp - 4]` is redundant.. Although `eax` is modified in loop, it is actually the required modification.. Remove the redundant lines as mentioned and analyze. You will get exact same data flow.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB: That's correct; GCC's "recipe" for using integer `cmpxchg` on `float` data apparently misleads it into doing redundant stores instead of just `movd`. 
 Does it help to use `-march=haswell` or something, instead of the default generic tuning?  See also [Atomic double floating point or SSE/AVX vector load/store on x86\_64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45055402) for some code-gen for pure-load and pure-store (even more dumb since it insists on using integer loads/stores instead of atomic SSE2 pure loads.)  My answer there also comments on the useless store/reload in an RMW.

Comment: This answer seems to be answering a different question, about the existence of the whole loop, not just the stores/loads instead of `movd`.